# Modal.propTypes - how to write definition with nested items

Tags: reactjs

I have this props and I like to write them into a Modal.propTypes Definition

```
'modalStyle': {
            'width': '800px',
            'height': '550px',
            'showOverlay': true,
            'showTitle': true,
            'title': 'my title'
        }
```

This does not work:

```
Modal.propTypes = {
// to do how to insert nested props
iframeProps: ({
    src: React.PropTypes.string,
    width: React.PropTypes.string,
    height: React.PropTypes.string
}),
modalProps: ({
    src: React.PropTypes.string,
    width: React.PropTypes.string,
    height: React.PropTypes.string,
    title: React.PropTypes.string,
    showTitle: React.PropTypes.bool,
    showOverlay: React.PropTypes.bool,
})};
```